# Reference of a saying of Hazrat Ali(R.A)

Tags: reference-request

I heard a saying referred to Hazrat Ali (R.A).

Saying is almost like that I recognized my lord by my broken determination

Answer (score 1):

You might be referring to Hadith #250 in Nahj al-Balaghah:

> Hadith n. 250
>
> 250. Amir al-mu'minin, peace be upon him, said: I came to know Allah, the Glorified, through the breaking of determinations, change of
>      intentions and losing of courage.
>
> وقال عليه السلام : عَرَفْتُ اللهَ سُبْحَانَهُ بِفَسْخِ الْعَزَائِمِ
> وَحَلِّ الْعُقُودِ

[Source](https://www.al-islam.org/nahjul-balagha-part-2-letters-and-sayings/selections-sayings-and-preaching-amir-al-muminin-ali#hadith-n-250)

(Note: the hadith number may vary slightly based on the print of Nahj al-Balaghah you are reading.)